# Raphaeljs resize canvas to fit content

Tags: javascript, raphael

In Raphaeljs I have content that is exceeding the canvas size. What I want to do is to have the canvas expand and have a container around the canvas that is scrollable so the user can view all of the content.

```
<div class="canvas_container" id="canvas_container">
  <svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is there any way that I can Resize the Raphaeljs canvas after all of the content has been loaded so that it fits everything? Basically, a "scale to fit". My canvas_container div is set to have a scrollable overflow, so if I can just get Raphaeljs to resize to fit everything then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all elements in your Raphael canvas and get the bounding boxes to calculate the size of your image and then resize the canvas.

The [Paper.forEach](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.forEach), [Element.getBBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox), and [Paper.setSize](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setSize) methods would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. I was hoping there was some nice "resize to fit" call or something that I was missing, but doesn't look like there is :)